# Could not find class 'gpr', referenced from method gps.a

Tags: java, android, gps, google-maps-api-2

I don't know why this error is occuring. I didn't update anything. I generated new keys from the google api console but the error is stil appearing. I wanted to do this example
[Android SearchView widget with Google Places API][1].

debug->res->values->google_maps_api.xml

I also have a release folder with the same structure and I entered the same key in both files.

Log:

```
3151-3151/com.example.onur I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services client version: 4242000

07-18 10:28:13.655    3151-3151/com.example.onur I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method guj.a, referenced from method gqi.a

07-18 10:28:13.655    3151-3151/com.example.onur W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 24936: Lguj;.a (Landroid/content/Context;)Lgri;

07-18 10:28:13.655    3151-3151/com.example.onur D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003

07-18 10:28:13.665    3151-3151/com.example.onur E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'gpr', referenced from method gps.a

07-18 10:28:13.665    3151-3151/com.example.onur W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpr;) in Lgps;

07-18 10:28:13.665    3151-3151/com.example.onur D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000

07-18 10:28:13.665    3151-3151/com.example.onur E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'gpr', referenced from method gps.a

07-18 10:28:13.665    3151-3151/com.example.onur W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpr;) in Lgps;

07-18 10:28:13.665    3151-3151/com.example.onur D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000

07-18 10:28:13.665    3151-3151/com.example.onur E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'gpr', referenced from method gps.a

07-18 10:28:13.665    3151-3151/com.example.onur W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpr;) in Lgps;

07-18 10:28:13.665    3151-3151/com.example.onur D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000

07-18 10:28:13.665    3151-3151/com.example.onur D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x5ea3 at 0x0a in Lgps;.a

07-18 10:28:13.665    3151-3151/com.example.onur D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x5ea3 at 0x0c in Lgps;.a

07-18 10:28:13.665    3151-3151/com.example.onur D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x5ea3 at 0x0a in Lgps;.a

07-18 10:28:13.685    3151-3151/com.example.onur I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services package version: 5084036

07-18 10:28:13.695    3151-3151/com.example.onur W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 20873 (t) in Lyp;

07-18 10:28:13.695    3151-3151/com.example.onur D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000e

07-18 10:28:13.700    3151-3151/com.example.onur W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 20873 (t) in Lyp;

07-18 10:28:13.700    3151-3151/com.example.onur D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000d

07-18 10:28:13.890    3151-3151/com.example.onur D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 502K, 15% free 9978K/11648K, paused 29ms, total 29ms

07-18 10:28:14.065    3151-3454/com.example.onur D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 313K, 14% free 10119K/11660K, paused 17ms, total 17ms

07-18 10:28:14.155    3151-3151/com.example.onur I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence; interface 4023 'Lgln;'

07-18 10:28:14.155    3151-3151/com.example.onur W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence;' failed

07-18 10:28:14.155    3151-3151/com.example.onur E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence', referenced from method glt.a

07-18 10:28:14.155    3151-3151/com.example.onur W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 2086 (Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence;) in Lglt;


  [1]: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-searchview-widget-with-google-places-api-using-actionbarsherlock-library/
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8fGG.jpg
```

Comment: have you had a chance to try any of the below solutions?

Comment: sorry i haven't had a chance to try it yet. thanks for your answer. I  appreciate it. I will let you know when I have tried it.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a few solutions:

1. first have you tried regenerating your API key?
2. When you go into the [google console](https://console.developers.google.com/project/), what does it say your package name is? Make sure its the correct package that your map activity is in.
3. After doing both of those, make sure to either clear data or uninstall the app you're working with - ***settings -> apps -> my_app ->*** and either ***clear data*** or ***uninstall***

Does that work? Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with thw Api key or the package name...
you just go through it...

probably the error can be in the manifest file or on the google console...

Answer (score -1):

Could you post your manifest? Sans API key, of course.

Your log looks almost identical to mine for a problem I've had recently, which was fixed by adding the following to the manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

I'm working on an application that was accessing maps just fine, then stopped out of the blue. I couldn't see anything actually pointing to a missing permission; I only picked up on it when I compared the manifest with another application that used maps api v2.

I'm still confused as to why it previously worked without it (Google says you need the permission for maps to work). Perhaps I'd once put it there and accidentally deleted the line, but either way putting it in is what fixed it.

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/android/config

Comment: It didn't work for me. I get the same error, althought I already had this permission in my manifest

Comment: Same here...
I had another error but I fixed it. Now my app is running (everything works) but i still get the error?